# Unable to load images from a Google Cloud Storage bucket in TensorFlow or Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I have a bucket on Google Cloud Storage that contains images for a TensorFlow model training. I'm using `tensorflow_cloud` to load the images stored in the bucket called `stereo-train` and the full URL to the directory with images is:

```
gs://stereo-train/data_scene_flow/training/dat
```

But using this path in the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` function, I get the error in the log in Google Cloud Console:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://stereo-train/data_scene_flow/training/dat'
```

How to fix this?

Code:

```
GCP_BUCKET = "stereo-train"

kitti_dir = os.path.join("gs://", GCP_BUCKET, "data_scene_flow")
kitti_training_dir = os.path.join(kitti_dir, "training", "dat")

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(kitti_training_dir, image_size=(375,1242), batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, label_mode=None)
```

Even when I use the following, it doesn't work:

```
filenames = np.sort(np.asarray(os.listdir(kitti_train))).tolist()
# Make a Dataset of image tensors by reading and decoding the files.
ds = list(map(lambda x: tf.io.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(kitti_train + x)), filenames))
```

`tf.io.read_file` instead of the keras function, I get the same error. How to fix this?

Comment: You cannot "fix it", its just that all keras functions do not take google cloud URLs, only normal filesystem paths.

Comment: What's the alternative to the Keras function?

Comment: Even when I use the following:
filenames = np.sort(np.asarray(os.listdir(kitti_train))).tolist()
# Make a Dataset of image tensors by reading and decoding the files.
ds = list(map(lambda x: tf.io.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(kitti_train + x)), filenames))
I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux or OSX you can use [Google Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) which will allow you to mount your bucket locally and use it like any other file system. Follow the [installation guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) and then mount your bucket somewhere on your system, ie.:

```
mkdir /mnt/buckets
gcsfuse gs://stereo-train /mnt/buckets
```

Then you should be able to use the paths from the mount point in your code and load the content from the bucket in Keras.

Comment: In my original code, I replaced the gs:// paths with local paths and ran the following before running the code:
gcsfuse gs://stereo-train ~/Documents/stereo-train
I get the error that ~/Documents/stereo-train doesn't exist on google cloud\

Comment: How to mount bucket locally using fuse?

Comment: You are using Windows, so there is no FUSE drivers for you OS, but there may be some alternatives, see here: https://serverfault.com/questions/831179/google-cloud-storage-mount-on-windows